# SQL query not workig as expected (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to run a simple MySQL query,but not sure why it is not working as expected. I have a table `clrs_how_to_reach` with following columns

- id
- state_name
- destination_name
- how_to_reach

above table have only one entry which I added for testing purpose.
When I am running following query

```
SELECT * FROM clrs_how_to_reach WHERE id=1
```

I am getting results and query showing me that it fetched 1 result, but when i am running following query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM clrs_how_to_reach 
WHERE state_name='himachal-pradesh' AND destination_name='dalhousie'

even select * from rest of query
```

not showing any result while both coloum have values i have used in query

Not sure why this is happening.
As an additional note, i am using wordpress, but i tried these queries on SQL console even.

**Edit**

When i changed  `state_name='himachal-pradesh'` to `state_name='himachalpradesh'`, i was able to get result,but i can not change that since application is using this convention throughout application.

Here is rsult for query `select * from clrs_how_to_reach where id=1;`

http://i42.tinypic.com/2vd4tmq.png

Comment: Can you paste us the result of `select * from clrs_how_to_reach where id=1` query?

Comment: Post some table data,might be a simple typo.

Comment: @AntoanMilkov: it say 1 record found and will show that slected record

Comment: @user2781057 This is exactly what I want to see the text of the record!

Comment: @AntoanMilkov:iupdated my post, issue is with have - in the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try like this:-

```
select count(*) as Column1 from clrs_how_to_reach 
where state_name ='himachalpradesh' and destination_name = 'dalhousie'
```

Do check if `himachal-pradesh` has a `(-)` in between in the column

**EDIT:-**

It may be that you have stored `himachalpradesh` in your sample data but in the actual data you may have the value as `himachal-pradesh`. Otherwise you may not get the value for `himachalpradesh` value.

Added the **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1887e/2)**

As you said the issue was with **column collation setting**

Comment: I want only exact result where state-name and destination-name should match

Comment: it is stored as 'himachal-pradesh'

Comment: I was not aware about this, i changed himachal-pradesh to himachalpradesh and was able to get result, but sadely i can not change it as such convention is being used a lot.

Comment: Obviously it's not stored as `himachal-pradesh` in the database if `state_name ='himachalpradesh'` returns results. Try `SELECT * FROM clrs_how_to_reach` to confirm. Maybe you've stared at the data for so long you just think you see the dash (happens to me).

Comment: @Anthony:no, i have checked, even i deleted sample data and than added new data but stillsame result

Comment: @RahulTripathi: I am storing data as himachal-pradesh, i changed that to test issue with -. I even cleared data from the database and filled it. i am using UI to fill data to database.

Comment: @Could you share the result which you get when you run the query as :-select * from clrs_how_to_reach where id=1

Comment: @user2781057 - Another thought, though it shouldn't matter... is the dash stored with one dash type (like an en-dash) and the query using another dash type (like hyphen)? Again, removing the dash means it's not stored with the dash. If you echo out `SELECT * FROM clrs_how_to_reach WHERE state_name ='himachalpradesh'`, are the dashes there?

Comment: @Anthony:- Thats why I have asked OP to share the data which is returned from the query result:- select * from clrs_how_to_reach where id=1

Comment: @RahulTripathi - Sorry, last comment meant for OP, not you. We're on the same page.

Comment: @RahulTripathi; i was not able to add images, i have added alink showing result screen for the query

Comment: @Anthony: i have added a link to image showing result when i am executing this query

Comment: @user2781057 - Can you copy the content of state_name and post it as a comment?

Comment: @Anthony: here it is himachal-pradesh

Comment: @user2781057:- Check this SQL Fiddle:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1887e/2 It is working great!!

Comment: @RahulTripathi: that is strange, can it be a issue with table encoding or any other property?

Comment: @user2781057:- Well that is really hard to say without really seeing your table structure and schema!!! But now I am sure that there is nothing wrong with the query :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: my bad , issue was with colum collation setting, Rahul can you please update your answer and i can mark it accepted

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? The only relation it has to the actual solution to the OP's problem is a quote of what the OP said himself!

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
select count(*) as result from clrs_how_to_reach where state_name='himachal-pradesh' and destination_name='dalhousie'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it was stored not like:

```
'himachal-pradesh'
```

But as:

```
'himachal–pradesh'
```

They may seam the same, but in fact they are not. Check the char codes!

Anyway it is very easy to combine both the cases without much sweat:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM clrs_how_to_reach 
WHERE state_name LIKE 'himachal_pradesh' AND destination_name='dalhousie';
```

Keep in mind that you can use "_" as any single character matching in MySQL LIKE statement.